# Jquery - change more backgrounds at the same time

Tags: jquery

I'm using four DIVs that look as follows:

```
<div class"first">1</div>
<div class"second">2</div>
<div class"third">3</div>
<div class"fourth">4</div>
```

If the cursor is over the "second" DIV, background of that DIV should change as well as the background of the previous div ("first"). Also, if the cursor hover over "third" DIV both previous ("first" and "second") should change the background color. If the cursor is over the div "fourth" the previous three DIVs ("first", "second" and "third") should change the background.

How can I do that using Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

===EDITED===

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw9YV/10/

try this html:

```
 <div id="group1">
    <div class="first hoverMe">1</div>
    <div class="second hoverMe">2</div>
    <div class="third hoverMe">3</div>
    <div class="fourth hoverMe">4</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="group2">
    <div class="first hoverMe">1</div>
    <div class="second hoverMe">2</div>
    <div class="third hoverMe">3</div>
    <div class="fourth hoverMe">4</div>
</div>​
```

and this js:

```
 $(".hoverMe").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#d3d3d3"); 
    $(this).prevAll(".hoverMe").css("background-color","#d3d3d3");
});

$(".hoverMe").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color",""); 
   $(this).prevAll(".hoverMe").css("background-color","");
});
​
```

Comment: does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: @Yaron Uliel - If I have more than one set of these DIVs, all of them below the last one that is selected will change background. Is it possible to make this code to affect only one set od this divs (the one affected with hover function) ?

Comment: @Sergio I've edited my answer to fit you request, the js stays the same while in the html you just need to wrap any the sets with some other `div` (if I understood your request correctly)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('div').hover(
function(){
    $(this).prevAll().css('background-color','#f00');
},
function(){
    $(this).prevAll().css('background-color','#fff');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/e9f4g/1/).

And please note that your HTML needs an `=` between the `class` and the `"first"` (etc).

Comment: Well, without `andSelf()`, it'd answer the op.

Comment: @gdoron, I knew there was *something* I meant to edit out... *runs to edit*... XD

Comment: @Shikiryu, you're absolutely right! For some reason I thought it was the previous elements *as well as* the 'self'. **Edited**.